# Error get all list items deleted_at is not null

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using gorm in my restful service, and I need to bring the deleted records.
I can't see how to bring them and I can't see it in the documentation

thanks everyone, i update the controller working,
Controller completed

```
func GetAllDeletedUsers(c *gin.Context) {
    var users []models.Application
    if err := db.DB.Unscoped().Where("deleted_at IS NOT NULL").Find(&users); err == nil {
        c.AbortWithStatus(404)
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        c.JSON(200, users)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Find-soft-deleted-records no ?

Comment: hi, is not null

Comment: making it unscoped should remove the automatically added clause `deleted_at is null`. Thus you should be able to execute `db.DB.Unscoped().Where("deleted_at IS NOT NULL").Find(&users)`

Comment: Hi, mh-cbon is perfect

Comment: if err := db.DB.Unscoped().Where("deleted_at IS NOT NULL").Find(&user); err == nil

Answer (score 1):

The one line answer:

```golang
if err := db.DB.Unscoped().Where("deleted_at IS NOT NULL").Find(&users); err != nil {
    c.AbortWithStatus(404)
    fmt.Println(err)
} else {
    c.JSON(200, application)
}
```

The docs link: [Find soft deleted records](https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Find-soft-deleted-records).

Answer (score 0):

One line answer:

```
If you want to find users that not deleted. Just remove your Where() clause.
```

**Explantion**

In gorm, if your model have gorm.Model in it, it will automatically add condition that '(delete_at != null)' when you query in table.

If you don't want that happed, you should add an Unscope() clause before Delete().

You can check document here:[Delete in Gorm](https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Delete-permanently)